# How do I resolve individual promise from a centralized listener?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have an event listener, which will receive event (from server) whenever a specific task is done. I desire each task to be encapsulated in a promise, so that I can construct complex ordered workflow in a clean manner.

How would I resolve each task promise (by id) from a global listener?
Here's an conceptual example of what I am trying to achieve.

```
// list of all tasks
var tasks = {}
tasks['id-1'] = getTask('id-1')
tasks['id-2'] = getTask('id-2')

// do task in order
// each task will issue request to server, and wait for reply 
tasks['id-1'].startPromise()
  .then(function(result) {

    // start second task from first task's data
    return tasks['id-2'].startPromise(result);
  })
  .then(function() {
    // finalized task works
    return true;
  });


// listen to task finish
client.listen('onReceive', function(event) {
  if(event.is('taskFinished')) {
    var id = event.taskId;
    tasks[id].resolve(event.result); //How do I resolve task from listener??
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with polling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you'd need a global mapping from ids to resolver functions.

```
const tasks = new Map;
function runTask(id, data) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        // if (tasks.has(id)) throw new Error("cannot run multiple "+id+" at once");
        tasks.set(id, resolve);
        client.fire('start', id, data); // or whatever you need to trigger the task
    })
}
client.on('taskFinished', event => { // or however you get notified of finished tasks
    const id = event.taskId;
    if (tasks.has(id)) {
        tasks.get(id)(event.result);
        tasks.delete(id);
    }
});
```

You can also use a plain object instead of the ES6 `Map` if you prefer (or need ES5 compatibility), and you might write the listener so that it is only active when the mapping is not empty.

You would use this like

```
runTask('id-1').then(result =>
    runTask('id-2', result)
).then(() => {
    console.log("both done");
    return true;
})
```

Comment: Thank for the answer, I didn't know you can just call function on the promise to resolve it.

Comment: I'm not calling anything on the promise, I'm calling the `resolve` function