# NodeJS Delaying function return statement until designated event handler finished

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm implementing SerialPort communication receiver.
SerialPort are connected to another machine that can handle various of jobs.

Which means multiple command can sent via Serial port with attaching ID and each function who call SerialCommunication should have corresponding response by ID.

Problem is SerialPort implementaion use Listener pattern since it is stream.

```js
class SerialPortClass {
  constructor() {
    this.serialPort = new SerialPort({ path: '/dev/USBtty0', baudRate: 115200 });
    this.parser = new DelimiterParser({ delimiter: ';', includeDelimiter: false });
    this.serialPort.pipe(this.parser);
    this.parser.on('data', async (data: string) => {
            const [id, ...data] = data.split(' ');
            // After resolving ID and should send data to corresponding caller.
        });
    this.parser.on('error', async (err: unknown) => {
            console.error(err);
        });
  }
}
```

```js
{
...
  public writeIntoSerial(id: string, data: string) {
    this.serialPort.write(`${id} ${data}`);
  }
...
}
```

```js
{
...
  public async waitUntilCommnucationDone(id: string): Promise<string> { // Returns string data which comes from serail output.
     // How to implement this?
     // Maybe using Promise?
  }
...
}
```

And usecase is like below,

```js
const operateJobA = asnyc (data: string): DATA => {
  const id: string = generateRandomId();
  serialPortClass.writeIntoSerial(id, `TYPE_A_OPERATION ${data}`);
  const raw_data: string = await serialPortClass.waitUntilCommunicationDone(id);
  return rawToData(raw_data);
}
```

## Implementation

1. Write into serialPort stream is guranteed to be one at a time by using MQ. (Actual calling of `writeIntoSerial` is on MQ).
2. `writeIntoSerial` is called by any of functions outside of this module. (Output stream order is not guranteed with input stream order)

The keypoint for this is how to impl. `waitUntilCommunicationDone` as Promise base for the other word, how to convert `sync` operation to `async`.

I have tried using Mutex or Semaphore or somethig in simple way(Add `completeIdList: string[]` in class and push completed `id` into that.), but I discarded changes since it seems it is not thread safe.

Any idea for implementing it? I dont care if there are quite many excessive job required or not).
I know if i give up on Promise return, it becomes easier but entier code in project will be affected.

Comment: Using external Database or something also ok.

Comment: Yes, use promises. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47674820/how-do-i-resolve-individual-promise-from-a-centralized-listener

Comment: @Bergi Thank you for comment, but it is different situations, inside `on`, function it seems it actively calling jobs needed but in my case, it isn't since external context which calling `writeIntoSerail` cannot be accessed by listener. Also worried about thread safeness.

Comment: It is exactly the same situation, your `this.parser.on('data', …)` event handler is being actively called, and either `writeIntoSerial` or `waitUntilCommunicationDone` should register the promise resolver by id.

Comment: Not sure why you are worried about thread safety. There is only one thread running your javascript code.

Comment: Ohh. Sorry for misunderstanding, Not I get it. Thank you for answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

From @Bergi's answer,

```js
class SerialPortClass {
  private results: Map<string, { resolve, reject }> = new Map();
  public constructor() {
    ...
    this.parser.on('data', async (data: string) => {
            const [id, ...data] = data.split(' ');
            if (this.serialResult.has(id)) {
                const { resolve } = this.serialResult.get('id');
                resolve(data);
            } else {
                throw new NoSuchSerialCommandError(`Unknown ID found ${id}`);
            }
        });
    ...
  }

  public writeIntoSerial(id: string, data: string): Promise<string> {
     this.serialPort.write(command);
        return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
            this.serialResult.set(sid, { resolve, reject });
        });
  }
}
```

And usecase

```
const operateJobA = asnyc (data: string): DATA => {
  const id: string = generateRandomId();
  
  const raw_data: string = await serialPortClass.writeIntoSerial(id, `TYPE_A_OPERATION ${data}`);
  return rawToData(raw_data);
}
```

No thread-safe issue exists since NodeJS execute one thread per time.